# Training of word weights in Word Embedding and Word2Vec

Tags: python, keras, word-embeddings, word2vec, mathematics

I want to know how are the word weights updated for the embedding layer in Keras and for Word2Vec. Like for the normal `model.add(Embedding(..))` and  `from gensim.models import Word2Vec`. Though after using `Word2Vec()` we put them in the Keras `Embedding` layer. So I want to know how this is being done mathematically.

I've gone through [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/270546/how-does-keras-embedding-layer-work), but I just still want a clear mathematical difference between Word2Vec and normal embedding. **I want to know the math, how is gradient descent used for updating the weights of the words, how is backpropagation done etc**.

P.S. What I understood is that `Word2Vec()` converts words into vector space and similar words are represented closer to each other. And in case of `Embedding`, unique integers are assigned, and represented in vector space. So are the words converted to one-hot vectors, or how are they just being put up as numerical values. I want to get this concept cleared, I haven't been able to find any resources which explain this difference mathematically from scratch.